# How I can convert from a Data frame into an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I am trying to convert a Dataframe into to an array using Python 2.7 but I got an error.

This is my code:

```
train = arff.loadarff(open('/Users/cristinamulas/train.arff', 'r')) 
train = pd.DataFrame([train])   
train = train[['sepal_length','sepal_width','petal_length','petal_width','CLASS_LABEL']].values
```

Error

```
File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2726, in _getitem_array
indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer.format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "['sepal_length' 'sepal_width' 'petal_length' 'petal_width' 'CLASS_LABEL'] not in index"
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access your columns correctly. The problem then either in the way you are loading your .arff file or the way you are creating your dataframe. Can you check if the dataframe has been created properly by printing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try directly following code

`train.values`

Remove column names from the code line.